# Alfresco: How to update repository-tier workflow files without restarting the tomcat server?

Tags: maven, tomcat, sdk, workflow, alfresco

I'm currently working on developing a custom workflow with many custom behaviors and scripts. I'm using the Alfresco Maven SDK to build and test my project as I develop it. This necessitates that I restart the repository-tier tomcat server every time I want to make a change/update my workflow files. I am getting quite frustrated with how long this takes each time, and it means that I'm wasting time while waiting for the server to restart, especially when I've made a small typo in one of my files.

I'm looking for a way (if it's possible) to update my files (in particular the bpmn process file) and apply these changes to my Alfresco instance without having to restart the tomcat servers each time. I've set  to true in my service-context.xml, and I have also tried to redeploy the workflow from the admin-workflow-console, but my changes do not take place unless I manually restart the server.

I am using: Alfresco Community 5.2, Maven SDK 2.2

Any tips or suggestions would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by
workflow admin console
URL

```
http://<server>:<port>/alfresco/s/admin/admin-workflowconsole
```

Ex ::  `deploy alfresco/workflow/<workflow-definition>.xml`

path for your workflow definition file.

Refer this docs for more information

https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5079-workflow-console

Comment: Hi @vikash, thanks again for your answer. I've tried this but it does not seem to be picking up the changes. Currently I am:

1. Making changes to the process definition file and saving it.
2. Running the deploy line in the workflow console
3. Logging out and back in to Alfresco share
4. Starting a new instance of the workflow

But it doesn't seem to recognise the changes

Comment: I may help more if you can please share your process definition file.

Comment: Please find the file at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By5ruty8M4IleWlKSmdQNUNXR0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes I know it is correct at the moment. The problem I have is that when I want to make additions to the process file it is taking a long time because I need to restart the server each time. Even though I have <redeploy> set to true and I am also using the workflow console to redeploy the workflow, nothing is changing. Do you have any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: please try with clean your project and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by that

Comment: clean your project with maven clean

Comment: Does this not necessitate me to shut down the server? Forgive me for all the questions, I am a beginner with this stuff :)

Comment: yes , you have to shutdown your server for project clean it will remove your temporary data stored in target folder.

Comment: Ok, I've run the clean command and I am now restarting the servers. Do you expect the workflow console method to work now? I will let you know if it does

Comment: My workflow still isn't updating when I Deploy it through the workflow console unfortunately

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?